# How can I reinstall Windows 10's calculator app?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, calculator

I uninstalled the Calculator app like this in PowerShell:

```
Get-AppxPackage *windowscalculator* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

How do I reinstall it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt185364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what the calculator store name is?

Comment: [See this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/224798/how-to-uninstall-windows-10s-built-in-apps-and-how-to-reinstall-them/)

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned below, I don't want to reinstall all the store apps. And the store name *windowscalculator* doesn't work with the script posted below. I tried *Microsoft.windowscalculator*, didn't work

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This one worked for me, just combined the commands from the other answers found here. Note: you have to use the `-Allusers` option with the `Get-AppxPackage` command since it is not installed anymore under your current user account:

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers *windowscalculator* | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}
```

Comment: Here's another variant of this answer:

    get-appxpackage -allusers *windowscalc* |foreach {$_.InstallLocation+"\AppxManifest.xml"} |add-appxpackage -disabledevelopmentmode -register

Comment: Make sure to run the PowerShell as an administrator. Otherwise, it might not work.

Comment: It can raise an error: "Get-AppxPackage : The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed. (Exception from HRESUL
T: 0x800706FD)". Probably should reinstall Microsoft Store.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the [MS Store link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/windows-calculator/9wzdncrfhvn5) to the Windows Calculator.

Note: This will only work if you have the Windows Store app installed.

Comment: Currently this link leads not to calculator.

Answer (score 2):

To reinstall an individual app use PowerShell and run it in admin mode.
Screenshots:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/mAKZe]

Next get the full name of all apps, e.g. Windows Calculator paste this snippet in PowerShell and hit enter:

`get-appxpackage -allusers | Select Name, PackageFullName`

For single full name of the desired app name, e.g. Windows Calculator paste this snippet in PowerShell and hit enter:

`Get-AppxPackage *windowscalculator*`

Now copy the full name that looks like this: 
`Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1601.49020.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe`

Finally the we are going to install that app again with this snippet:

`Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_10.1603.12020.0_
x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\appxmanifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode`

Re-installed app is available without restart of the PC!

N.b: To remove individual apps use this code:
`Get-AppxPackage *alarms* | Remove-AppxPackage`

A list of all apps when removing is ([Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/224798/how-to-uninstall-windows-10s-built-in-apps-and-how-to-reinstall-them/))

Comment: Are you reinstalling WindowsAlarms or WindowsCalculator? I get `Add-AppxPackage : Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1712.3351.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\appxmanifest.xml' because it does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

Try `Get-AppxPackage *windowscalculator* | Add-AppxPackage`

or the following to install all default apps:
`Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers| Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}`

Comment: Thanks. I already tried `Add-AppxPackage` but there is no success or fail message - nothing happens. Unless I have to restart windows, which I haven't tried since I have a lot open/running. I know it's possible to reinstall everything, but there should surely be a command to install individual core apps?

Comment: The first command does nothing, the second one wants installation media.

Comment: @ajeh It's important to run the commands in PowerShell, as an admin (right click and "Run as Administrator"). Not sure why it would ask for installation media, but in the worst case, you can always flash a USB with with Windows 10: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0):

Just install it from the Windows Store if you have that installed.
Windows Calculator | https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfhvn5

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where I installed a stripped version of Windows 10 (for performance gains and lower latency) and the Calculator was missing.

I managed to find the old Windows 7 calculator and install it easily. Just google "old calculator for windows 10" and the first link should be from winaero website.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an FYI, the other answers above work, BUT if you're on an AD domain and a VPN, going to Microsoft Store may not work because you could be blocked.  Try the command line if the store blocks you.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1906.53.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You can download it from here:

https://www.filehorse.com/download-windows-calculator/download/

Virus total report:

https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/07a9fa95285def3865a7e0e8879a19a2b2a320b4f7ec95015cef8f8a82561744/detection

Comment: Once someone downloads this unknown package how exactly in specific detail do they install it? Edit your answer to include this vital information

Comment: It is a windows install package from Microsoft. To install open it and click install.