# Windows 10 Calculator is gone

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

I'm trying to open the calculator app on my Windows 10 64 bit machine.

When I search for calc in the start menu and click it, I get an error

> you'll need a new app to open this

I tried re-registering my windows ten apps by using this command

```
Get-AppXPackage | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

with a powershell running as administrator and the same issue still occurs.

How can I fix my calculator?

Comment: Did you try Unistalling it with `Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsCalculator | Remove-AppxPackage` and then reinstalling from the app store?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/978877/how-to-re-install-windows-10-calculator-app?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

Press WinKey + R, and type this and press {ENTER}:

```
%systemroot%\system32\calc.exe
```

If Calculator doesn't open, try these two PowerShell commands.

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.WindowsCalculator -allusers | select PackageFullName
```

Note down the Package ID from the last command. For instance, if the Package ID is displayed as "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1601.49020.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe", mention it in the next command:

```
Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1601.49020.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode
```

Make a note of the error messages, if any.

Comment: I had the App Icon missing from my tray and this fixed it. Thanks!