# Can anyone tell me that why my Calculator name got changed to something chinese?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Suddenly my Calculator name got changed to something chinese and I don't know how to revert it..!

Please take a look at the following screenshot as : 
[image]

Comment: @Biswa : Thanks it worked.Can you post it as answer and I will accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to uninstall the calculator app and reinstall it from Windows store. Or you can manually uninstall calculator a PowerShell command::

`Get-AppxPackage *windowscalculator* | Remove-AppxPackage`

You can get more here::

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ouc1too/2013/11/02/how-to-remove-windows-8-1-store-apps-with-powershell-when-they-wont-go-quietly/

[How can I reinstall Windows 10's calculator app?](https://superuser.com/questions/978877/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-10s-calculator-app)

You can also use CCleaner to uninstall the calculator app.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that your computer is infected by a badly-written Chinese virus
that replaced your calculator program.

I would suggest to scan your computer deeply with several anti-virus
products, including first Windows Defender and [Malwarebytes Free](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/).
You may also follow with some online anti-virus scans that do not need installation. See the article
[Test comparison - Which is the best free online antivirus scanner?](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/test-comparison-what-best-free-online-antivirus-scanner).

Then follow with [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) to check system integrity.

If the calculator does not change back, delete the program and copy it from
another computer. The best solution in that case is to do a clean re-install
of Windows, but that might not be convenient.

Comment: Thanks for the answer though but Biswa comment helped me restored the Calculator with correct name but I will follow up on your answer to go in the deep for the issue.!

Answer (score -1):

Just found this help thread through Google, I was just experiencing the same problem.  I went to settings - applications - calculator - advanced options, then reset the app.  It went back to English and is fine now.