# Windows Calculator: ESC and Return no longer work

Tags: windows-10, calculator

Since a recent Windows update, Windows' Calculator (calc.exe) no longer respond to keypresses of <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> on my numeric pad.
Has something changed?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing has changed and all these keystrokes work fine on my Windows 10 version 1909.

Evidently, something went wrong with your upgrade to (probably) version 1909.

I suggest checking for errors, then if not fixed to repeat the upgrade:

- Run `chkdsk`.
- Do
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html),
  taking good notice of any unfixed errors.
  Fixed errors might mean that the problem was solved.
  See also using DISM in the article
  [Use DISM to fix issues SFC can't](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/03/16/use-dism-to-fix-issues-sfc-cant/).
- [Reinstall Windows 10's calculator app](https://superuser.com/questions/978877/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-10s-calculator-app).
- If required,
  [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html),
  to return all Windows components to a known state.
  This is the same as doing again the same upgrade, so take the same precautions.

Comment: Sounds like [blasting a mosquito with a bazooka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument). I'm still suspecting some regional setting or input device configuration option. Also I'm currently still on v 1809.

Comment: Not the first two, which can point to the problem. I thought of another one which is now listed as third. The last one is in case no direction is found, and can be replaced in your case by just upgrading Windows in the usual manner (which might be a good idea in any case).