# 32Bit Windows Calculator produces wrong results in Windows 10 LTSC 2019 (Build 1809)

Tags: windows, windows-10, 64-bit, 32-bit

I was just wondering why the Windows calculator that comes with the LTSC-version of Windows (which actually is the old classic calculator from Windows 7, because the LTSC version does not come with the new modern UI calculator installed) is producting wrong results, or crashes when switched to "Programmer mode".

Steps to reproduce:

- Install Windows 10 LTSC 2019 64Bit or 32Bit
- open a 32Bit cmd.exe (deault in the 32Bit system of course, run from the Syswow64-folder on 64Bit system)
- start calc.exe
- you will notice that the calculator starts with "1" displayed instead of 0
- perform any calculation, i.e. SQRT(9) -> will produce wrong result. Switching to "Programmer mode" makes the calculator crash.

Question: how can this be solved? It happens on all LTSC systems I tried, so I think this is a general bug in the latest LTSC versions. Especially painful in the pure 32Bit system, because you cannot force the 64Bit version here (which would work for the 64Bit version).

Comment: Why not contact Microsoft support?

Answer (score 0):

That is now an old version of Windows.

Go to Settings, Apps, and scroll down to Calculator.

1. Try Resetting it and see if that works.
2. More likely:  Uninstall it, restart the computer, and then go to the Microsoft Store and reinstall the Calculator.

If the Store approach does not or cannot work for you, follow the Power Shell approach here:

[How can I reinstall Windows 10's calculator app?](https://superuser.com/questions/978877/how-can-i-reinstall-windows-10s-calculator-app)

Calculator is working fine here but my Windows is up to date.

Comment: I am talking about the LTSC version, there is no WIndows store there. Of course my LTSC 2019 version is up to date.

Comment: I posted a Power Shell approach to reinstall Calculator.

Comment: Reinstalling calculator will not help here, because the version included in the LTSC version is NOT the one from the Store, it's not even a UWP app.